# Why do I get a 400 on Jenkins update center?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, devops, jenkins-plugins

We use Jenkins 2.190.1 (we are stuck with this version because a lot of our infraestructure depends on all implementations).

Since 2 months ago we get an error like this when trying to run pipelines on newly created servers only

`Invalid tool ID 10.13.0`

The example above happens with NodeJS when selecting one of the available installations on the 'Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH' option on the job configuration page, If we uncheck that box so that it uses the default one, it works fine.

Most solutions online and even CloudBees suggest to go into Advanced Plugin Config and hit 'Check Now' but that does not work since we get a 400 error

`There were errors checking the update sites: IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/update-center/devoptics/update-center.json?id=devoptics&version=2.190.`

We checked the URL of the update center which points to http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

We've tried installing plugins manually and changing the URL of the update center.

PD: Prior to this, we had to disable gpg check on yum because the key provided by Jenkins would throw a `No key installed for <package>`  when installing anything but the latest version.

Any info on why might be causing this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the url to 'https' and restart the instance.
You can modify that under "<jenkins_home>/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml"